# My twilio client app doesn't connect with the call

Tags: javascript, php, twilio

I created a demo twilio client app following the tutorial here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/incoming-calls

It seems everything works fine. When I call the number the web app seems to respond but gets disconnected immediately. And the log element shows "call ended" where I didn't even pick up the phone yet.

Hope somebody knows how to fix it X(

Comment: [These folks probably know.](https://support.twilio.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I have sent a ticket. Still waiting for their email though

Comment: I'd expect them to be a little slow this week, given the holiday.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I suppose it might just be the ssl certificate issue since I'm running the app locally with ngrok

Comment: Did Twilio support get back to you? If not, can you share your code that you're using for this?